# How to pass query strings to the Identity Provider via Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

I want to use google (either pre-configured, or configure it myself as a custom OIDC idp) via Cognito. However I want to be able to provide the query string for `prompt=consent` and `access_type=offline` to get the refresh token and force a login every time to keep the token up to date.

Normally if I was using Google directly I would just pass these onto the `/authorize` route however now that I have Cognito, it does not seem that cognito forwards the query string when I call cognito's `/authorize`.

What did I miss?